# Webpack dynamically create a module

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am writing a plugin which creates a SVG sprite. It globs over the directories, merge SVG files in one image and returns the result. The idea is to dynamically create a module (which contains merged images) so that other modules can require it as an usual module. Or maybe you can suggest a more elegant solution?

**Config**

```
{
  plugins: [
    new SvgSpritePlugin({
      sprites: {
        icons: 'images/svg/icons/*.svg',
        logos: 'images/svg/logos/*.svg',
        socials: 'images/svg/logos/{twitter,youtube,facebook}.svg',
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

**Somewhere in the application**

```
var logosSprite = require('sprite/logos'); // require dynamically created module
document.body.appendChild(logoSprite);
```

Comment: I'm trying to do a similar thing.  Would love to know how to inject a module from a plugin.

Comment: Did you try [webpack-svgstore-plugin](https://github.com/lgordey/webpack-svgstore-plugin)? Looks like it solves the same problem.

Comment: @Kreozot svgstore-plugin does different thing - it emit assets during webpack compilation. I want to work with svg like with regular modules and build only required files. I write [svg-sprite-loader](http://github.com/kisenka/webpack-svg-sprite-loader) (highly experimental).

Comment: @4m1r the right way to doing this is to write a loader (see the [comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1310#issuecomment-125997245) from Tobias Koppers, the webpack author).

Comment: do you have a non-"elegant" solution for this already? Feels like you're trying to do too many things at once. You should be able to use webpack to combine all your svg and output a single svg with loaders and a plugin to bunch them all. Once you've figured it out, you need to determine how to make it available in the app.

Comment: I recommend to have a look at this plugin: https://github.com/rmarscher/virtual-module-webpack-plugin , which help you create a virtual file on the fly, and then you could include this file in entry config.

Answer (score 3):

Try taking a look at how external and delegated modules are provided in Webpack. A good place to start is the [`ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/ExternalModuleFactoryPlugin.js) or [`DllReferencePlugin`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/DllReferencePlugin.js).

Essentially, you create a plugin for the `NormalModuleFactory` which takes requests for modules, you match those which should resolve to the modules you are generating and you can asynchronously respond with a `Module`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a somewhat not-so-elegant solution.Combine all svgs(by iterating over folder)into one html and hide that html snippet with a `display:none`.Have the ids as the fileName and ucan then access them by `getElementById(<yourID>).innerHTML`. Sample of jsp based snippet..or write in whichever language you want..

```
<div id="hiddenSVGSprite" style="dispaly:none">
 <i><span id="Download" ><%@include file="svg/Download.svg" %>/span>Download</i>
 <i><span id="DownloadFAQs" ><%@include file="svg/DownloadFAQs.svg" %> </span>DownloadFAQs</i>
 <i><span id="DownloadQuickReferenceGuide" ><%@include file="svg/DownloadQuickReferenceGuide.svg" %> </span>DownloadQuickReferenceGuide</i>
 <i><span id="DownloadUserManual" ><%@include file="svg/DownloadUserManual.svg" %> </span>DownloadUserManual</i>
</div>
```