# Load multiple modules using single import

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I use Webpack to load SVG icons. Most icons have some CSS associated with it. I would like to keep styles for each icon in separate file. So it's needed some convenient way to include it in CSS bundle if icon is imported.
For example

```
import arrowIcon from 'icons/arrow.svg'
```

must:

1) load 'icons/arrow.svg' using my SVG loader

2) load 'icons/arrow.svg.css' using my CSS loader

**My attempts**

I could use `multi-loader` for that, but I don't know how to modify resource path `arrow.svg` => `arrow.css` to pass it to CSS loader. I could use `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` for that, but it seems to modify path for both loaders.
Also I could write my own loader which modifies path and invokes CSS loader, but don't know how to properly execute loader inside loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43989540/3602201) answer helped me to write a **plugin**

```
const CommonJsRequireDependency = require("webpack/lib/dependencies/CommonJsRequireDependency");
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function LinkedModulePlugin(options) {
    this.options = options;
}

LinkedModulePlugin.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('LinkedModulePlugin', compilation => {
        compilation.hooks.succeedModule.tap('LinkedModulePlugin', module => {
            const { resource } = module;
            const { test, linkedModule } = this.options;
            if (test instanceof RegExp && test.test(resource) ||
                typeof test === 'function' && test(resource)) {
                const linkedModulePath = linkedModule(resource);

                if (fs.existsSync(linkedModulePath)) {
                    const relPath = path.relative(module.context, linkedModulePath);
                    module.dependencies.push(new CommonJsRequireDependency('./' + relPath, null))
                }
            }
        });
    });
};

module.exports = LinkedModulePlugin;
```

**Usage example:**

```
// Webpack config
const LinkedModuleWebpackPlugin = require('./path/to/linked-module-webpack-plugin');

// ...

plugins: [
    new LinkedModuleWebpackPlugin({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        linkedModule: (resource) => resource + '.css'
    })
]
```

Anyway, It would be nice to be able to do it using **loader**.